# Why the window border and minimize/maximize/close buttons aren't showed in Debian for an app with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I'm coding an app with JavaFX, but when I execute it, It doesn't show the window border nor minimize/maximize/close buttons.
I'm using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>12</version>
    </dependency>
```

And when I run a HelloWorld, I get only a white panel with the label (I need to stop the app from the IDE in order to close it).

[image]

I tried with:

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);
```

But same result.

Comment: Might be a bug. What if you try the latest version of JavaFX (13.0.1)?

Comment: I tried it, same result.